# TFS Having branchs with different folder structure

Tags: tfs

I'm using TFS as my main version control. We are working on an embedded solution for different embedded proprietary hardware. Each hardware solution directory structure is different from another solution. But the main source files are the same but they reside in different directory structure. for example:

```
ProjectCollection
  FirstEmbedSolution
       src
           main.cpp
       inc
           main.h
  secondEmbedSolution
       src
           MainModule
               main.cpp
       inc
           MainModule
               main.h
```

I want these solution to be branched from a main branch so the new changes in the can merged and re-based efficiently. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't modify a branch and not expect the modification will be reflect on main...
But you can branch part of main folder, but I don't see how this is better. I think the architecture of your solution is wrong, if you need diferente configuration branch's per solution.

Comment: I agree with you that we must change the solution layout.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried branching your current structure as is, and then performing a move operation in TFS. This will get you the structure you require and TFS should remember the old and new paths and allow you to carry on branching. I'm guessing so it might not work but I'm sure I have similar situations that have appeared over time that mimic this behaviour that you want

Comment: I tried what you suggested before but project related files(solution and project definitions) is also needed and for them we really need two separate repositories. If we maintain two separate repos, I think it is better to codes to be separated.